# L293D, Raspberry Pi3, 12 V DC Motor - GND connection?

Tags: pi-3, power-supply

Is this correct connection of GND? Will I not fry the Pi?

5 V from Pi to power L293D, (9-12 V)battery to power DC. 9 V minus and Pi GND pin connected together with L293D GND.

[image: Photo of circuit on breadboard]

[image: Closeup of circuit on breadboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to power the L293D logic (pin 16) with 3V3.  If you can that is likely to be more reliable as the Pi's GPIO will clearly be able to set logic low and logic high (typically a high need to be >70% of logic power).

The motor power (pin 8) will be happy with 9-12V.

Yes, the battery -ve, Pi ground, and L293D grounds should all be connected.

Comment: Thanks 4 answer. I understand everything except this thing about pin 8(TXDO?). What do You mean? Do I need that?